# Liferay cannot successfully validate reCaptcha

Tags: validation, liferay, recaptcha

I have tried to enable reCaptcha in liferay portal, but it always fails on text verification 'Text verification failed'.

If anybody has experiences with Liferay and reCaptcha, any advice will be  appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ticket already raised in Liferay JIRA for the same.

Please refer this. https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-46355